# Rails activerecord has_many to has_many, query all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having some trouble querying through a table, it works fine if I select only one record, but If I select multiple it doesn't work. For example

```
    Orders Table
      |
    / | \
OrderProducts Table
    \ | /
      |
    Products Table
```

Orders model

```
has_many :order_products
has_many :products, :through => :order_products
```

OrderProducts model

```
belongs_to :order
belongs_to :product
```

Products model

```
has_many :order_products
has_many :orders, :through => :order_products
```

Activerecord queries

```
Order.find(1).products // this works
Order.where(type_id:1).products // this doesn't seem to work
```

Is it not possible to query multiple items in this manner? What would be the best way to go about querying multiple records from another table based on this structure or would I need to update my model structure? I appreciate all the help! Thanks again!

Comment: Try with Order.where(type_id:1).first.products

Comment: This is similar to example I put that works, because I think it's only looking at one record. I would like to take into account multiple records, say if type_id returned 3 records, I would like to query 'products' based on the 3 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@orders_ids = [1, 5, 6]
Order.where(id: @orders_ids).map{|order| order.products }
```

it will return products for Order with id 1, 5, 6

**implement this in a view:**

in controller action:

```
@orders_ids = [1, 5, 6]
@orders = Order.where(id: @orders_ids)
```

in html.erb:

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
  <%= order.number %>
  <% order.products.each do |product| %>
    <%= product.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: let me know if this helped you, if not I'll try to revise it or delete it.

Comment: Thanks! was just about to manually join the tables, thought there would be a quick ruby/activerecord way to do this.